# Is it possible to "window" fullscreen games?

Tags: display, games, fullscreen, thunderbolt-display

Is it possible to force an OpenGL app into a window instead of fullscreen canvas?

I'm using two displays and would like to use the other, while playing a game on one display. Since fullscreen makes the secondary display go black, this it not possible by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a generic way, but a lot of games give you the option if you hold down option when starting.